# Node Identifier of copied node in Jackrabbit not found while deleting

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, dms, jcr-sql2

I copied a node in Jackrabbit using `session.getWorkspace().copy(sourceNode.getPath(), destinationNode.getPath())`

This operation changes are persisted instantly as far as I know. But when I tried to get the copied node for deleting it using `session.getNodeByIdentifier("nodeId of copied node")`, it gives ItemNotFoundException. The reason for that error is that the copied node loses is `mix:referenceable` property during copy which causes getNodeByIdentifier to fail.

The question is how do I set the `mix:referenceable` property to copied node as I m not able to get the node from session after copy operation. Could someone help me out on this?

UPDATE:

**CODE:**

```
    Node srcNode = session.getNodeByIdentifier("SOURCE_NODE_ID");
    if(srcNode == null) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }

    Node rootNode = session.getRootNode();
    Node appNode  = rootNode.getNode("JACKRABBIT");
    Node destNode = appNode.addNode("Copy_Test_"+System.currentTimeMillis(),"nt:file");

    session.getWorkspace().copy(srcNode.getPath(),destNode.getPath());
    destNode.addMixin(MIX_VERSIONABLE);
    destNode.addMixin(MIX_LOCKABLE);
    destNode.addMixin(MIX_REFERENCEABLE);
    destNode.addNode(DMSConstants.RESOURCE_NODE,"nt:unstructured");
    session.refresh(true);
    session.save();
```

**EXCEPTION:**

> Exception in thread "main" javax.jcr.InvalidItemStateException: Unable to update a stale item: item.save()
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.server.ServerObject.getRepositoryException(ServerObject.java:111)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.server.ServerSession.save(ServerSession.java:265)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.server.ServerXASession_Stub.save(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.client.ClientSession.save(ClientSession.java:272)

Please note that I am using JCR 2.0 Also if I change the code to `session.refresh(false)`, the code works fine but I m not able to find the node identifier from session for deleting the same which is my original issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating a node at the destination then copying to the same place? I believe the stale exception is because the call to `copy` has updated the underlying node making your `destNode` reference stale/out-of-date.

Simply remove the `addNode` then do something like ...

```
String destPath = "Copy_Test_" + System.currentTimeMillis()";
session.getWorkspace().copy(srcNode.getPath(), destPath);
Node destNode = session.getPath(destPath);
```

Comment: I craked it sometime back. Thanks for the answer any how.

Answer (score 0):

As @TedTrippin pointed out the issue was with creating a destination node before copy which was not required. As part of copy, the node is created. So my final working code is as follows:

```
Node srcNode = session.getNodeByIdentifier("SOURCE_NODE_ID");
if(srcNode == null) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}

Node rootNode = session.getRootNode();
Node appNode  = rootNode.getNode("JACKRABBIT");    
String destNodeName = "Copy_Test";  
session.getWorkspace().copy(srcNode.getPath(),appNode.getPath() + "/" + destNodeName);
Node destNode = appNode.getNode(destNodeName);
destNode.addMixin(MIX_VERSIONABLE);
destNode.addMixin(MIX_LOCKABLE);
destNode.addMixin(MIX_REFERENCEABLE);    
session.refresh(true);
session.save();
```